# cx_Oracle ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, pip, importerror, cx-oracle

I have successfully installed cx_Oracle using pip. but when i am trying to import it in python. It displays error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
PS C:\Users\singishi> pip install cx_oracle
Collecting cx_oracle
Installing collected packages: cx-oracle
Successfully installed cx-oracle-5.2.1
PS C:\Users\singishi> python
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hxqs.png)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have multiple versions of Python installed and the pip you are using refers to a different version of Python than the one you are running. You can make sure that is not the problem by running this command:

```
python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade
```

Another possibility is that you don't have an Oracle client installation in your PATH environment variable, which is easily checked.

If both of these issues aren't at fault you'll need to dig deeper. Perhaps check the cx_Oracle.pyd that pip installed for its dependencies and make sure they are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

My system runs Win 10 x64 and has the Anaconda 2 distribution of Python 2.7. I'm using the jupyter notebook for accessing Python from Anaconda.

Here's a rough order of how I got this to work:
1) Install oracle instant client *for the same version of cx_oracle*. Note on the cx_oracle download page that the file name indicates whether it is 12c or 11g. I have 12c an therefore needed to use the instant client for 12_2. 
2) Installation of the instant client must be to the same parent folder as my SQL Developer. For whatever reason, this did not work until I put this in the same parent folder, so that \Oracle shares a parent with \SQLDeveloper.
3) Include the path for oracle instant client in your Windows environment variable called 'PATH'.
4) Create a new variable in Windows environment called 'ORACLE_HOME'.
5) Then install cx_oracle from pip. Uninstall it first if you've already installed it.
6) Now try to import it.

Answer (score 0):

cx_oracle requires one more package to be installed i.e., SQLAlchemy.
So, Installed SQLAlchemy using pip.
I tried this and it works for me.